# Is it possible to focus the same textbox on it's onBlur() event?

Tags: javascript, html

I have HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="text1" onBlur="focusMe(this.id);" />
```

and javascript function:

```
function focusMe(Id)
{
document.getElementById(Id).focus();
}
```

Comment: @nickf - Did you see the title of the question?

Comment: Yeah I saw it, but there's code which has been written and we're being asked if it works? Just run it and find out, geez!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible:

```
function focusMe(Id) {
    setTimeout(function() {document.getElementById(Id).focus();}, 0);
}
```

Your script is not working because onBlur is called just *before* the focus is lost.

Two remarks:

- you'd better use a reference to the input rather than its id
- why do this?!

Comment: If there is only a single text input field, it might make sense to force the focus on it.

Answer (score 0):

I would just pass the control directly. Why pass the ID just to get the control back from it again?

Markup:

```
<input type="text" id="text1" onBlur="focusMe(this);" />
```

Javascript:

```
function focusMe(elem)
{
  elem.focus();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, running your code shows that [**it doesn't work**](http://jsbin.com/oqabu), and probably with very good reason.

Since I'm here, I should point out that you can actually pass a reference to `this` rather than `this.id` and save some hassle:

```
onBlur="focusMe(this)"

function focusMe(el) {
    el.focus();
}
```

But it doesn't work anyway, so it's a tad moot.